# how to get particular attribute image in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added one image media attribute called "maattabel" to attribute set.

I have also uploaded image and selected maattabel option for that image while creating product.

[image]

Now how to get this image on the product detail page.

I want this image not to be displayed with other image list but want to display in other area like in details section.

How to get this image having particular attribute added maattabel.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'maattabel', $_image["file"])`? That's how you would get the thumbnail or small image on a product page; not sure if it works with custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','whateverlabel')->getFile();  ?>
```